# jQuery/CSS button not functioning as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jplayer

I have a on/off button that i took from [this tutorial](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css3-on-off-button/) and implemented the button on my jPlayer page.

- As you can see in the tutorial the button has 2 states: pressed and
  unpressed
- I implemented the button on my page using the jquery file of the
  modified Player.

if i try to implement it in the index.html it changes to pressed but wont play, if i implement it inside jQuery it wont change to pressed but will play.

This is my code inside `metroplayer.js`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('#button').on('click', function(){
                $(this).toggleClass('on');
            });
        });

(function($){
    $.fn.extend({


        metroPlayer: function(options) {

            var defaults = {

            }

            var options =  $.extend(defaults, options);

            return this.each(function() {
                obj = $(this);
                o = options;

                $template = $('<div id="metro-wrapper">'+
                '<div id="metro-left-overlay"></div>'+
                '<div id="jp_container_N" class="">'+
                '<div id="jquery_jplayer_N" class="jp-jplayer"></div>'+
                '<div class="jp-gui">'+
                '<div class="jp-interface">'+
                '<div id="metro-left">'+
                '<div id="metro-controls">'+
                '<ul>'+
                //'<li id="metro-prev" class="jp-prev"><img src="img/prev.png" /></li>'+
                '<section><a id="button" class="onoffbutton jp-play" href="#">&#xF011;</a>'+
                '<span></span>'+
                '</section>'+
```

What is wrong in the code that prevents the button to appear at "pressed" mode?

This is my player [page](http://www.tranceil.fm/player2).

Comment: can you stick this up on jsfiddle will make it easier to debug

Answer (score 1):

Simply adding a css class to your button element won't trigger the jPlayer element to start playing. Try adding this inside your click event function:

```
if( $(this).hasClass("on") ){
    $(yourplayerid).jPlayer( "play" );
} else {
    $(yourplayerid).jPlayer( "stop" );
}
```

Source:
http://www.jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#jPlayer-play

Comment: Sorry I just realized you're using metroplayer.js and not jPlayer. I can't find the metroplayer documentation but you must use the according play trigger function. I think it's based off of jPlayer though so try `$(yourplayerid).metroPlayer( "play" );`

Comment: $('#player').metroPlayer( "play" ); wont trigger the playback...:( if you look into the source code of my index page you can see the #player jquery initiation

Comment: and i reinserted the button call just like the example says, in the index, not jquery

Comment: I think `.jPlayer( "play" );` was working please check again. The only problem is that it doesn't toggle off when you click the button again. Check my original response.

Comment: It starts playing when I click it. I don't any songs in the playlist however what is the music source?

Comment: the source is a .json file which have a stream link....and its weird, i cant play it for some reason..

Comment: dose it also go into 'pressed' state?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't implemented the actual `jPlayer( "play" );` on your click event.
I think what you want to do is

```
$('#button').on('click', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('on');
    $musicPlayer.jPlayer({ //whatever json you want })("play");
});
```

Or something like that.
And that means you have to move this event binding to AFTER setting up your player on `$musicPlayer`, so make sure you do that.